# Power Automate Send As - Co Owner's permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, power-automate, send-email, connection

I have a Power Automate flow that sends an email after a form submission.  My client wants those emails to come from a specific mailbox (PMOAdmin).  I don't have Send As permissions for that mailbox, and they're not going to grant them to me.  However, I added a co-owner to the Flow who DOES have Send As permissions for that mailbox.  My question is, can we leverage her access to that mailbox by adding her name to the Connections (Offixe 365 Users, Sharepoint) that for right now only have my name?  Like, if I click New Connection and add her account here, would that then allow this flow to send from that mailbox?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, But the connection for the `send an mail (V2)` action must be created from her account. You need to sign in to Power Automate under her account, go to `send an email (V2)` action in the flow and create a new connection with `+Add new connection` under her credentials.

Then you just expand *Show advanced option* and add that mailbox to `From (Send as)`

[image: Outlook - send an email (V2)]